# Direct download latest version of GAE SDK Python

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, buildout

I use bildout and jenkins to build my Python GAE application.

The problem is that after each new version Google moves the sdk and replaces the new one from 
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/*

Right now I use the hardcoded url in my buildout:

```
[gae_sdk]
# Dowloads and extracts the App Engine SDK.
recipe = appfy.recipe.gae:sdk
url = https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.12.zip
hash-name = false
destination = ${buildout:parts-directory}
clear-destination = true
```

Does anybody have a way to force downloading the latest version each time?
I'm looking for an out-of-the-box solution but it looks like google doesn't have anything like https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_latest.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed, [appfy.recipe.gae](https://github.com/prmtl/appfy.recipe.gae) allows you to download Google App Engine SDKs

In order to download the latest version you must remove the [URL](https://github.com/prmtl/appfy.recipe.gae/blob/e3e09784d2e1372c67d5cc456ec3274378c8d1e5/appfy/recipe/gae/sdk.py#L11) parameter

```
:url: URL to the App Engine SDK file. Default is to download the latest version
    from storage.googleapis.com.
```

It reads the latest SDKs versions from

https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/appengine-sdks/o?prefix=featured

Comment: Just wanted to point that this solution doesn't always work 100% stable but it's the best option available now.

Comment: Hi, what are the issues you experience sometimes with the recipe?

Comment: The xml which the recipe used had a version of the SDK which wasn't publicly available (but it was listed on it)